# JQuery UI 1.8 and Internet Explorer 8 Performance Issues?

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8

Just an open end question - keen to hear the expert opinions out there.

I have developed a one page website which is pretty user interface and animation intensive.

I am using the following frameworks:

- Jquery 1.7.1
- Jquery UI 1.8

I have done testing in Firefox 8 which works perfectly, little to no latency on animation and other user inteface effects.

However tests on Internet Explorer 8 have been glitchy. The animation has undesirable latency issues and the whole interface is a bit unresponsive.

Does any one have any suggestions on how to fix this, perhaps some patches and/or quick fixes that I could generically apply to the page to imporve performance issues?

Thanks - looking forward to your answers.

Wez

Answer (score 0):

The javascript engine in IE 8 is alot slower then IE 9 and other browsers, one thing you can do is use: http://www.webpagetest.org . 

And basicly watch the CPU load on the graph, it should be a quick and dirty way of finding out if your animations are to much for the IE8 javascript engine.

Comment: I think this will be a great site, would be great to somehow get a view of which processes / threads are slowing down the whole system, that way we will get a better feeling of what jquery functionality does not play nice with IE

Answer (score 0):

You should always make sure that you are not mixing jQuery animations AND CSS animations on the same page - therein lies a boiled CPU.

IE9 on Win 7 should be fine due to hardware acceleration, but don't use that browser as your testing benchmark, remember to test for your users who will be using older browsers.

Comment: Thanks for this...........can you please explain to me what you mean by jQuery animations AND CSS animations? I am quite new to Jquery, I thought that Jquery was CSS animation?